# rafalib - as.fumeric error " 'x' must be a character"

Tags: r

Generating a plot with rafalib open.

Have a dataset with a column labeled "Tissue". The entire table is in object "b". "hc" contains a hclust of the distribution of the numeric values of "b".

When I run:

```
myplclust(hc, xlab="distance",main="Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram",labels=b$Tissue,lab.col=as.fumeric(b$Tissue),cex=0.5)
```

RStudio responds with:

> Error in as.fumeric(b$Tissue) : 'x' must be a character

What's going on here? I've reset R multiple times. I have rafalib installed and active.

Comment: tidyverse is also running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

The names I was entering under this function were being recognized as data rather than values for some reason. By converting my list to a vector with `as.vector` inside of the `as.fumeric` function, the problem was solved.

The correct code now looks like;

`myplclust(hc, xlab="distance",main="Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram",labels=b$Tissue,lab.col=as.fumeric(as.vector(b$Tissue)),cex=0.5)`